# Jquery selector on Django loop

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-4, selector

So I have this

```
{% for producto in reparto_martes %}
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow product-box">
          <img class="card-img-top product-photo" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src={{ producto.foto }} data-holder-rendered="true">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-text producto_precio">${{ producto.precio }}</h4>
            <h5 class="card-text producto_nombre">{{ producto.nombre }}</h5>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success anadir_button">Añadir</button>
              <small class="text-muted"></small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

It looks like this: https://gyazo.com/0b329d87af9372250a53ae25347b59b0

I need to select the items name when the user clicks on the anadir_button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".anadir_button").click(function(){
        $('.producto_precio').clone().appendTo('#list_pedidos');
    });
});
```

^This one just selects all the three items (Bananas, bolson frutal, almendras)

```
$('.producto_precio').last()clone().appendTo('#list_pedidos');
```

^And this one just selects 'almendras'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from your current clicked button and navigate to the closest **.card-body** ancestor. Now you can find the corresponding product.

Here is an example:

```js
$(".anadir_button").click(function(e){
  console.log($(this).closest('.card-body').find('.producto_nombre').text());
                   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow product-box">
            <img class="card-img-top product-photo" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src={{ producto.foto }} data-holder-rendered="true">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-text producto_precio">$0</h4>
                <h5 class="card-text producto_nombre">Bananas</h5>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success anadir_button">Añadir</button>
                    <small class="text-muted"></small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow product-box">
            <img class="card-img-top product-photo" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src={{ producto.foto }} data-holder-rendered="true">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-text producto_precio">$0</h4>
                <h5 class="card-text producto_nombre">Bolson frutal</h5>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success anadir_button">Añadir</button>
                    <small class="text-muted"></small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow product-box">
            <img class="card-img-top product-photo" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src={{ producto.foto }} data-holder-rendered="true">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-text producto_precio">$0</h4>
                <h5 class="card-text producto_nombre">Almendras</h5>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success anadir_button">Añadir</button>
                    <small class="text-muted"></small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```